# Android: user ID account (not ID phone)

Tags: android, userid, google-account

I have an app that save the user image but i would save with each image also user id.

The user can change telephone device but the google account is always the same.

I need a code string that identify the user and not the phone.

Maybe a numeric id, not necessarily google account email.

I have this code but is wrong (return device id and not user id)

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephoneCode = tm.getDeviceId();
```

or

```
String code=Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

## # # # # # # # # #

I have test with

```
AccountManager mgr = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
Account[] accounts = mgr.getAccountsByType("com.google");
String userCode=accounts.toString();
```

In this code return a string:

```
[Landroid.accounts.Account;@318ca48b
```

This alphanumeric code always change!

Thank's
Daniele.

Comment: what else did you expect to get calling toString() on array? You should get the first element for example: accounts[0].name

Comment: I already have.
The request was for more than a year ago.
thanks anyway for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());

Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

for (Account a: accounts) {
    if (a.name.contains("@gmail.com")) {
        return a.name;
    }
}
```

This will return the first account that ends in @gmail.com; there can be more than one.

Comment: Sorry but I tried to put in "MyApp" the name of my app but report always error.
I have an java file Application:
`public class AppHttpMethod extends Application`

and a java file for Activity:
`public class ImageOperationActivity extends Activity`

In my AndroidManifest.xml i have the tag
`<application android:name="AppHttpMethod"...
    <activity android:name=".ImageOperationActivity"...`

In "MyApp" what should I put?
Very thank's for your time :-)

Comment: I have used this code  

`AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
 for (Account a: accounts) {
  if (a.name.contains("@gmail.com"))
      {
         AccountName=a.name;
      }
 }`

Comment: It seems from your code above that you can get at your context via getApplicationContext() since I am guessing you are calling from within an Activity. So for you getApplicationContext() works just fine. I will update the answer to reflect this. I was running this code via a background thread that did not run in the context of an Activity. So to make that work I get a reference to the application context from my class that extends the Application class which I called MyApp.

Comment: is there any difference in the behavior, when using the Activity context or application context?