# Run IAP check for piracy prevention after installation

Tags: android

My app has been pirated recently and I'm trying to prevent further losses in revenue.
I am using an In App Purchase system to purchase the premium version of the app.

Apparently someone bought my app and released a pirated version by doing a backup (where premium= true)
Now i would like to run an IAP check when my app is installed to check if the user really has purchased the premium version.
Is there a way to do this as soon as my app is installed or updated?

**UPDATE:**
I have to run the IAP without using SharedPreferences as they can easily be backed up and the backup distributed

Comment: "an in app purchase system".  Which one?

Comment: Official Play Store IAP, my app is distributed only on the play store

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check it once a day (or week)? You can set the SharedPreference to the last time a successful check was completed. Of course, you'll want to check for future dates and reject those, since that's what I'd do to get around a system like that. You might want to give a 24-hour leeway on future dates to accommodate for time-zone changing, but it shouldn't be too hard.

This way, even if someone backed up your app, it would only work for the next day or so before checking again.

To be honest, though, this might not help much. If people are pirating your app, they'll find ways to get around (just about) anything you throw at them.

Comment: I believe this wouldn't solve my problem, someone can do a backup of the latest version and the above method wouldn't work.
The only solution is to run the code without using SharedPreferences as they can easily be backed up

Comment: My app is very lightweight and most users use it all the time and multiple times a day, so doing so would be too heavy to handle, this method is best for games that run a few times a week so doing a check at startup wouldn't be too much annoying for the user

Comment: In my case this wouldn't be the best idea, my other thought would be to use the Alarm Manager to run a check every few days or so, but I've read that it has to turn on the screen to run and it would be something pretty annoying for some people, so I'm looking for a solution that can be run while the users is using the device

Comment: I'm gonna wait for some other ideas, as an AlarmManager will turn on the screen and it might be annoying.

Comment: I didn't mean with an AlarmManager. I meant check the time on each startup. Only if it's expired do you run IAP, within the app.

Comment: Ohh now i get it, but it looks pretty complicated to implement, i would need a calendar to manage it, and i don't know any way do to it.
I've searched on Google how to do it and it looks like i need to use an AlarmManager anyway.

Comment: You could just use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get a millisecond-based timestamp. You don't need a calendar.

Comment: I think i've found an even better way to do it, i will try to use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676217/android-user-id-account-not-id-phone
I will save the user ID, then everytime the app will run i will check if the User ID is the same as saved, if it's null or different it will run a check, if it's the same it will skip.
So if someone makes a backup it will have an user ID which is unique, also if someone pirates it the ID will be saved and eventually i can retrieve it and discover who is pirating my apps

Comment: Ok, good luck! Like I said, though, they'll get around it if they really want to. Don't make the mistake of putting *too* much effort into what will eventually be broken anyway.